# Mercurial hg pull hg up hg merge heads blah blah the whole process not very clear

Tags: mercurial

We are using Kiln as our mercurial server and I there are three developers working on the same repo and i get this issue often and I am not quite sure what is happening.
Every once in a while I will do an `hg pull`.
Then when I run hg up I get the following message

> abort: crosses branches (use 'hg merge' to merge or use 'hg update -C'
>   to discard changes )

ok so I run `hg merge` and I get

> abort: outstanding uncommitted changes (use 'hg status' to list
>   changes)

ok so I run `hg status` and I get something like this

```
! Safemail 3.0\CSM3.0\AddinSetup\Release\AddinSetup.tmp 
! Safemail 3.0\CSM3.0\Outlook2007Addin\Outlook2007Addin_TemporaryKey.pfx
```

no idea what to do with that.

If I run `hg commit` again it says no changes.
Finally if i run `hg heads` I get

```
changeset:   51:daea74a29d5c
tag:         tip
parent:      49:b88e6e522672
user:        Rahul Chandran
date:        Mon Jan 23 13:30:54 2012 -0800
summary:     added login code

changeset:   50:cb6f6e1eec5e
parent:      46:d83431c322ad
user:        dthompson@Jabberwock.lan
date:        Mon Jan 16 22:10:11 2012 -0600
summary:     Adjusted Email-PDF formatting
```

Clearly I do not come from a DSCS background and I am probably missing some basic understanding of what is going on . Any help appreciated.
What I do know is that the code that my co worker checked in via a push has like no files in common with my changes.   I would not expect like a merge conflict or some such in a non distributed source control system . essentially I am having some trouble understanding what is happening here exactly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the help for `hg status`.  It will tell you that `!` means:

```
  ! = missing (deleted by non-hg command, but still tracked)
```

So you deleted some files that are tracked in your repository.  If you didn't mean to track them in the first place (they look like good `.hgignore` candidates) you can `hg forget FILENAMES; hg commit` them.  If, instead, you do mean to track them you can `hg revert FILENAMES` them (to get them back into your working dir from your repository.

Once `hg status` agrees you have no uncommitted changes you'll be able to `hg merge`.

Consider taking a little time to read the first few chapters of the (free) Mercurial book.  These basic concepts are easy when presented well and in order, but horribly frustrating when you try to pick them up piecemeal from google searches and Stack Overflow questions.  It's worth the 30 minutes to save you hours.

Comment: worked, thanks a ton and yes your advice about the book sounds good will do it asap :-)

Comment: +1 for recommending the (excellent) documentation. @Rahul, you might also have seen references to [hginit.com](http://hginit.com).

Comment: What's the Mercurial book and what's the link. [I will end up googling for it.. but that makes it easier for the next person looking at this post.]